# How to make NSComboBox lose focus after selection?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nscombobox

I have a combo box in my OSX app and I want it to lose focus right after I change the value selection.

Right now it just stays selected and highlighted after the selection.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured this out myself.

Using NSComboBoxDelegate, I use this method

```
- (void)comboBoxWillDismiss:(NSNotification *)notification
```

It's getting called right before the pop-up list is going to be dismissed. Inside that method I'm calling:

```
[myComboBox setRefusesFirstResponder:YES];
```

and it does the trick.